# solace consumer attach MessageListener warning

Tags: java, jms, messaging, consumer, solace

I'm trying to user a JMS implementation to send/receive message at #Solace Appliance.

I'm using `SolConnectionFactoryImpl` factory to create the connection.
Everything look's Ok but when I'm trying to attach the `MessageListener` event to the JMS `MessageConsumer`, the API of Solace its printing the following message

> ago 26, 2016 12:40:28 PM com.solacesystems.jms.SolTopicSubscriber
>   setMessageListener INFORMACIÓN: Setting message listener in
>   SolTopicSubscriber null

Here I create the `MessageListener`:

```
MessageListener messageListenerConsumer = new MessageListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message arg0) 
    {
        try {
            textPane_1.setText(textPane_1.getText()+"puerquito consumido:"+((TextMessage)arg0).getText()+"\n");
            textPane.setText(textPane.getText()+"puerquito consumido\n");
        } catch(Exception er) {
            textPane.setText(textPane.getText()+"Error al consumir el puerquito\n");
        }                       
    }
};
consumerParameter.setMessageListener(messageListenerConsumer);
```

Here I create the consumer and attach the `MessageListener`

```
messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
messageConsumer.setMessageListener(consumerParameter.getMessageListener());
```

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Which version of the JMS API are you running?

This log entry is expected and has been moved to DEBUG in the latest versions.

Here is an example from JMS 7.2.0.557.

```
594  [main] DEBUG com.solacesystems.jms.SolTopicSubscriber  - Setting message listener in SolTopicSubscriber null
```